# Comparing columns in separate .txt files

Tags: unix, awk

This has been asked a multitude of times but for some reason my solution is not working. Two .txt files:

**File1.txt**

```
I   27804   C   A   0.987700768 1024    0.518987342
I   27810   T   C   0.99418488  1054    0.518987342
I   27816   G   A   0.994650485 1085    0.518987342
I   27822   T   C   0.998170732 1097    0.518987342
I   27825   C   T   0.998170732 1101    0.518987342
```

**File2.txt**

```
I   27804   .   C   A   1115.77
I   27810   .   T   C   1141.77
I   27816   .   G   A   1141.77
I   27822   .   T   C   1141.77
I   27823   .   C   A   1141.77
I   27825   .   C   T   1141.77
```

File2.txt contains a large number of columns (not shown for clarity).

I wish to use $1,$2,$3 and $4 in File1.txt in order to identify the corresponding lines in File2.txt - and then print the full File2.txt line.

Desired output would be:

```
I   27804   .   C   A   1115.77
I   27810   .   T   C   1141.77
I   27816   .   G   A   1141.77
I   27822   .   T   C   1141.77
I   27825   .   C   T   1141.77
```

With this entry skipped:

```
I   27823   .   C   A   1141.77
```

As it is not present in File1.txt.

I've tried simply using:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1,$2,$3,$4]=$0;next}{if(b=a[$1,$2,$4,$5]){print b}}' file1.txt file2.txt
```

But this appears to not only return File1.txt lines - but simply reprints the entirety of File1.txt. What have I done wrong?

Comment: `b=a[...]` is assignment. And if you don't need the line from `file1.txt` then you don't need to store it in `a` in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1$2$3$4];next}{b=$1$2$4$5;if(b in a){print}}' file1.txt file2.txt
```